# Average time between purchases

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to find the average amount of time between the same customer makes purchases.
I get weird decimals when I try to do avg(date_diff). I can get sum(date_diff) to add the difference in dates together, but I need an average. when i do sum(date_diff)/count(*) I get different weird decimals.
As far as all of the 1000 pages I've read, this should work, but it's obviously not right. Thanks in advance

````
SELECT
        customerid
        ,avg(date_diff(purchase_date, prior_purchase, day))  as time_between_purchases
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        customerid
        ,parse_date('%Y%m%d', DATE) as purchase_date
        ,lag(parse_date('%Y%m%d', DATE))
            over(partition by customerid order by parse_date('%Y%m%d', DATE) asc) 
            as prior_purchase
    FROM `data`)
GROUP BY customerid```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum(date_diff(....))` should be the difference between the 1st and last order.

Your query works as expected:

```
With data as (
    Select 0 customerid, DATE from  unnest(["20200122","20200222","20200322","20200422","20200522"]) DATE UNION ALL
    Select 0 customerid, DATE from  unnest(["20200222"]) DATE UNION ALL
    Select 1 customerid, DATE from  unnest(["20200122","20200222","20200322","20200422","20200522"]) DATE UNION ALL
    Select 2 customerid, DATE from  unnest(["20200122","20200222","20200322","20200422","20200522"]) DATE UNION ALL
    Select 2 customerid, DATE from  unnest(["20200122","20200222","20200322","20200422","20200522"]) DATE UNION ALL
    Select 10 customerid, DATE from  unnest(["20210101","20210102","20210103"]) DATE 
    )

SELECT
        customerid
        ,avg(date_diff(purchase_date, prior_purchase, day))  as time_between_purchases
        ,sum(date_diff(purchase_date, prior_purchase, day))  as day_customer
        ,count(purchase_date)  as count_orders
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        customerid
        ,parse_date('%Y%m%d', DATE) as purchase_date
        ,lag(parse_date('%Y%m%d', DATE))
            over(partition by customerid order by parse_date('%Y%m%d', DATE) asc) 
            as prior_purchase
    FROM data)
GROUP BY customerid
```

having decimals as average is normal.